# AWS IoT Java SDK v2 in Docker 20 min disconnect - error core 1051

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, aws-sdk

I am trying to run Java SDK version 2 code inside Docker. After about 20 minutes there is a disconnect with error code:

> 1051 <[AWS_IO_SOCKET_CLOSED] socket is closed>;

but no such error occurs when I run it pc locally or on an ec2 instance.

My sources and Dockerfile:

```
private final MqttClientConnectionEvents callbacks = new MqttClientConnectionEvents() {
    public void onConnectionInterrupted(int code) {
        log.warn("Interruptor <{}> : [{}] {}", code, CRT.awsErrorName(code), CRT.awsErrorString(code));
    }

    public void onConnectionResumed(boolean flag) {
        log.warn("Resuming: {} [true if the session has been resumed.]", flag);
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> subscribe());
    }
};

@Value("${service.description}")
private String description;
@Value(value = "${aws.iot.endpoint}")
private String endpoint;
@Value(value = "${aws.iot.clientId}")
private String clientId;

@Value(value = "${aws.iot.access}")
private String access;
@Value(value = "${aws.iot.secret}")
private String secret;

private CompletableFuture<JSONObject> async(MqttAbstract req) {
    final MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(req.getTopic(), req.bytes(), QualityOfService.AT_LEAST_ONCE);

    executor.execute(() -> {
        log.info("Pub-ing to [{}]: {}", req.getTopic(), new String(message.getPayload()));
        this.publish(message);
    });

    return registry.waitForMqtt(req.getBody().getPayload().getRequestId());
}

private void subscribe(InternalResponses topic) {
    try {
        this.connection.subscribe(topic.getTopic(), QualityOfService.AT_LEAST_ONCE, topic.getHandler()).get();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        log.error("subscribe [{}]: {}", exc.getClass().getSimpleName(), exc.getMessage());
    }
}

private void subscribe() {
    log.info("Starting subscribing...");
    try {
        this.subscribe(new InternalResponses(gateways, this.registry));
    } catch (Exception error) {
        log.error("onApplicationEvent [{}]: {}", error.getClass().getSimpleName(), error.getMessage());
    }
}

public void publish(MqttMessage message) {
    try {
        log.info("Publish to {}", message.getTopic());
        executor.execute(() -> connection.publish(message));
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        log.error("publish: {} - {}", e.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
    }
}

@PostConstruct
public void construct() {
    final CredentialsProvider provider = new StaticCredentialsProvider.StaticCredentialsProviderBuilder()
            .withAccessKeyId(access.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            .withSecretAccessKey(secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            .build();

    try (AwsIotMqttConnectionBuilder builder = AwsIotMqttConnectionBuilder
            .newDefaultBuilder()
            .withEndpoint(endpoint)
            .withClientId(clientId)
            .withConnectionEventCallbacks(callbacks)
            .withProtocolOperationTimeoutMs(MINUTE)
            .withCleanSession(true)
            .withWebsockets(true)
            .withWebsocketSigningRegion("eu-north-1")
            .withWebsocketCredentialsProvider(provider)) {
        this.connection = builder.build();
        this.connection.connect()
                       .whenCompleteAsync((connectResult, error) -> this.subscribe());
        log.info("{} to [{}] as {}", description, endpoint, clientId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("postConstruct: {} - {}", e.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
    }
}

@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
    log.info("Shutting down [{}]", description);
}
```

Is there something wrong with the connection/timeouts config or with the Dockerfile?

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk    
COPY build/libs/* /
COPY app.sh /app.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/app.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/app.sh"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain what's going wrong, but I was having the same problem and it went away after I updated to version 1.16.0 of the AWS IoT Device SDK.

I'm not 100% sure it's solved. But before the update I could reliably get this issue to happen by leaving my container running overnight, and now it's been running for 6 days straight without any trouble.